# why req.body is always empty and req.files is always undefined when sending form-data

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman, body-parser

I'm trying to send form-data to nodejs but req.body is always empty and req.files is undefined. Here is my code 
***index.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const config = require('./config/database');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const router = express.Router();
const products = require('./routes/product')(router);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.use('/products', products);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port + ' in ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' mode');
});
```

**and in product.js file**

```
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();


module.exports = (router) => {

  router.post('/newProduct', (req, res) => {
          console.log('req');
          console.log( req.body );
          console.log( req.files );
})
}
```

Comment: I assume by 'form-data' you mean `multipart/form-data` for file uploads?
 `body-parser` doesn't support multipart bodies, see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html I'd suggest trying `multer` https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Comment: it halps, thank you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest at least reading the [multer readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

You need to tell multer to upload the file or files for each route.

For example

```
router.post('/newProduct', upload.array('files', 5), (req, res) => {
          console.log('req');
          console.log( req.body );
          console.log( req.files );
})
```

Or you can also use `upload.single()` for a single file or `upload.fields()` to handle multiple upload form fields. But all this is better explained in their page.